# Join two files based on column value. Original File has repeated values

Tags: regex, bash, join, awk, sed

My two Files look something like the following:

File 1:

```
18 1600000 + CAA 0 1
18 1600000 - CAC 0 11
18 1600000 - CAC 0 3
18 1600000 - CAC 0 5
18 1600001 - CAA 0 11
18 1600001 + CCC 0 1
18 1600001 - CCC 0 3
18 1600002 - CAT 0 1
18 1600002 - CAT 0 3
```

File 2:

```
18 1600000 + CGG 6 6
18 1600000 - CGT 0 2
18 1600001 - CCC 0 3
18 1600001 + CGG 0 11
18 1600001 - CGG 9 9
18 1600002 - CAT 0 1
18 1600002 - CAT 0 3
18 1600002 + CAT 0 6
18 1600002 + CCA 0 5
```

I want to `join` the two files based on column 2 but put a NULL value where there is no match. In File 1 there are 4 rows with 1600000 and only 2 rows in File 2. So I want the output to be like the following:

```
18 1600000 + CAA 0 1    1600000 + CGG 6 6
18 1600000 - CAC 0 11   1600000 - CGT 0 2
18 1600000 - CAC 0 3
18 1600000 - CAC 0 5
18 1600001 - CAA 0 11   1600001 - CCC 0 3
18 1600001 + CCC 0 1    1600001 + CGG 0 11
18 1600001 - CCC 0 3    1600001 - CGG 9 9
18 1600002 - CAT 0 1    1600002 - CAT 0 3
18 1600002 - CAT 0 3    1600002 + CAT 0 6
                        1600002 + CCA 0 5
....
```

I believe the `join` command may be an issue because it only uses 1 file as the template. So if there were extra values in File 2 I think those would be lost. So a more complicated `awk` argument may work better. Each file has some rows that the other does not.

Comment: The `-e` or `-a` options to `join` may help you do what you want.

Comment: What if a joining column is present in file2 and not in file1? For example what is the expected output for the rows having 1600002 in the second column? Do you want to see two rows (like in file1) or four rows(like in file2)?

Comment: Mauro - Edited Question to reflect your comment. That was what I meant when saying `join` would be problemsome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `awk` like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{sub(/^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+/, ""); a[$1,++c[$1]]=$0; next} 
     {print $0, a[$2,++d[$2]]}' OFS='\t' file2 file1
```

**Output:**

```
18 1600000 + CAA 0 1    1600000 + CGG 6 6
18 1600000 - CAC 0 11   1600000 - CGT 0 2
18 1600000 - CAC 0 3
18 1600000 - CAC 0 5
18 1600001 - CAA 0 11   1600001 - CCC 0 3
18 1600001 + CCC 0 1    1600001 + CGG 0 11
18 1600001 - CCC 0 3    1600001 - CGG 9 9
18 1600002 - CAT 0 1    1600002 - CAT 0 1
18 1600002 - CAT 0 3    1600002 - CAT 0 3
```

This awk command uses an associative array with composite key as `2nd column + an incrementing counter per 2nd column value`. `sub` function is used to discard 1st column's value from 2nd file as that's not desired in output.

Comment: This is a very nice solution if OP is looking for a "left outer join", not for a "full outer join". Upvoting anyhow because it is really instructive.

Comment: This seems to just output the second file. I edited my question to maybe make things more clear. I do not wish to throw out values but add blanks when there is no more matching values.

Comment: I've added generated output in my answer. Most likely you have DOS line endings in your input files. You can run `dos2unix` to remove them OR else use this gnu-awk: **`awk -v RS='\r\n' 'NR==FNR{sub(/^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+/, ""); a[$1,++c[$1]]=$0; next} {print $0, a[$2,++d[$2]]}' OFS='\t' file2 file1`**